# Are positions without decimals valid GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson

I'm trying to understand the https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946 specification.

Are positions without decimals allowed or not?

It says:

> A position is an array of numbers.  There MUST be two or more
> elements.  The first two elements are longitude and latitude, or
> easting and northing, precisely in that order and using decimal
> numbers.  Altitude or elevation MAY be included as an optional third
> element.

But att the same time "A position is an array of numbers."

A number can according to RFC7159 also be a integer ...

So by example, is this valid?

```
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-109,51],"type":"Point"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"area":0}}
```

Or should it be:

```
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-109.0,51.0],"type":"Point"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"area":0}}
```

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-6 seems to indicate both are acceptable

Comment: Yes! That's what's so confusing? It contradicts with "The first two elements are longitude and latitude, or easting and northing, precisely in that order and using decimal numbers."- also, every example is written with the 70.0, instead of 70 notation?

Comment: It's not a contradiction. the fractional part is optional ~ `number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]`

Comment: Integral coordinates are only really useful for spaceborne operations. This does not seem to be a practical question.

Comment: @nmtoken Sorry about this being a topic of my limited language/math/semantic knowledge, but you mean that "decimal numbers" could very well be 1, 2 or 5? Not 1.0, 2.0, 5.0?

Comment: @Vince This is exceptions within a database, I guess the location is rounded.

Comment: Yes, that's what RFC 7159 tells us, and GeoJSON (RFC 7946) is a profile of RFC 7159.